# "The value provided for the report parameter 'enddate' is not valid for its type. (rsReportParameterTypeMismatch)" in SSRS v8

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am getting the above error whenever I try to run the report.  My region settings are set to date format "dd-MM-yyyy', the calendar control displays the date in that format as expected but when I run the report I get the above error.  I have checked tregion settings, made sure the report language property is set to the correct regional language (in this case en-ZA) but the report still seems to expect the date in American format and only works when I manually enter the date in American format instead of selecting via the calendar control which returns it in regional format.

Anyone know why it would return this error when it seems that all the date formats are set the same both on the machine and within the report?

Comment: Is the parameter type set to date?

Comment: Yes, that is what is making it so frustrating.  Region settings match server settings which are set in the report as well with the date format of the field set to the same format.  I cannot see why it seems to be insisting on US format when none of the dates in the system are set to US format.

Comment: Have you tried running in SSMS with a variable declared as a date?

Comment: Nope, I'll give it a shot after today's crisis fixes are done!

Comment: You could also try setting the date format just before the select statement. SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

Comment: Just not working, just got them capturing as a string and then converting to a datetime in the sql statement.  very frustrating

Comment: Can you post some example data?